# Mercurial (TortoiseHG) won't commit after manually deleting some files

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I removed some database files from my project using the search function in Explorer. After that Mercurial complains that it cannot find the files an refuses to commit. I tried using the shelve tool, but I run then in a bugreport for version 2.5 of TortoiseHG stating that the node holding the database file could not be found.
'
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it possible you deleted not only the files in your working directory but also down in the data store itself (`.hg/....`)?  It's possible to do that if you search indelicately in explorer.  Here's the command line equivalent:

```
ry4an@four:~/projects/unblog$ find . -name '*.xml*'
./static/attachments/2005-09-22-isle-royale.gpx.xml
./.hg/store/data/static/attachments/2005-09-22-isle-royale.gpx.xml.i
```

It is entirely safe and okay for me to delete that .gpx.xml file, but if I deleted every file with `.gpx.xml` in the name then I'd be deleting the file from the store and corrupting my repository.

Try running `hg verify` in the repository and see what output you get.

Comment: You (and the trash bin) saved me!